# using egs view engine on angularjs template

Tags: express, angularjs-directive, ejs

I am using express.js in the servers-side and I am using ejs as my view engine , in the client-side i used Angularjs , I used Angularjs Directives as tags :-

```
   angular.
   module('myNav',[]).
   directive('myNav', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/navbar/navbar.template.html',
        transclude: true ,
        scope: {
        }
      }
    });
```

and in html:

```
<my-nav> </my-nav>
```

i want to use ejs engine on my template (e.g. templates/navbar/navbar.template.html).
it contains code like

```
<%if (user) {%>
   ......
  <% } %>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: you want to use template engine as ejs without using angular own rendering?

Comment: i dont think so , I am using angular directives :- that means i define a directive and use it in html <my-directive></my-directive> ,  what angular dose is replacing this tag with other html code in a file called template , in the template file i want to use ejs code and filters (<%  ...  %>).